# Why XA only in Bindings mode?

Tags: ibm-mq

This article indicates that if MQ has to be used as a Transaction Manager, the application has to compulsorily use Bindings mode. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0601_ritchie/0601_ritchie.html
Bindings mode also means that the MQ Server and the application both have to be on the same host because it uses JNI.

My question is, what is the fundamental reason behind this requirement? Why can't MQ Manager work like JBOSS which can reside on any host and take requests for managing distributed transactions?

What prevents WMQ from supporting client connection for distributed transactions?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: This question has been answered here http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=72313

Answer (score 2):

That article is very old, it was from 2006, for a long time now MQ clients that are located remote from a queue manager have been able to use XA transactions.

MQ supports XA with JMS when using a supported transaction manager within a JEE container

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032590_.htm?lang=en